# Why am I seeing the `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Form)"` error, when upgrading the React version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS upgrade from `15.4.1` to `16.8.6` but right now I'm seeing the error mentioned in the title:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Form)"

I see that this question has been asked a few times around here, but what I've understood is that the `<Provider>` needs to wrap the `<App>`; since my `app.js` already has the `<Provider>` at the top, what am I missing?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Form, configureStore, history } from 'some-external-library';

import Page from 'components/page';
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Form>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Page} />
        </Switch>
      </Form>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Now that you upgraded React, you need to upgrade ConnectedRouter and react-redux too in order to use the new context API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that I had two versions of `react-redux`in my project (one in `package.json` and one in `example/package.json`). Removing the second one has fixed the issue, as mentioned here:

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1117#issuecomment-477389213

Thanks to @markerikson

The issue would likely be because different copies of `React-Redux` are ending up in your application. Since our internal `ReactReduxContext` instance is a singleton, if two different parts of the app are using different copies of `React-Redux`, they're not using the same `ReactReduxContext` instance, and so the connected components can't talk to `<Provider>`.